# Web2py profile change submit redirect

Tags: web2py

In web2py in user/profile after applying change and clicking "apply change" it redirects to index page, is there a way to redirect it to another page? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your auth settings, include:

```
auth.settings.profile_next = URL('some_controller', 'some_function')
```

The above defaults to `/default/index`.

Also, note that this setting only applies when there is no `_next` variable in the URL query string. If a user clicks on the "Profile" link in the auth navbar, the URL of the current page will be added as the `_next` variable of the query string, and the user will be redirected back to that page after updating the profile.

Comment: Great. Maybe accept the answer so it's clear for future readers.